# Is there a Chrome equivalent to the Firefox JS Print Setup addon?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there an addon to Chrome or a setting I can tick where I can print silently?

[JS Print Setup](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/) is a Firefox addon which instantiates a JavaScript object that lets you print silently. I'd settle for something like that or better yet, a way to set Chrome to print silently to a specific printer all the time.

Comment: Why are you making us Google [JS Print Setup](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/)?

Comment: Sorry, I had the context in my mind all day so I forgot nobody else was thinking it :/

Answer (score -1):

Apparently there isn't. In Chrome you can enter into kiosk mode and that has the option of turning off the print dialog, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for as I need to use the web page windowed.